# OpenGL: what is the BEST texture format for depth infomation?

Tags: opengl, textures, depth

I am the new one here, and I have a question about the texture format in OpenGL for depth infomation, there is part of my code:

```
glGenTextures(1,&tex);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE16UI_EXT, width, height, 0, GL_LUMINANCE_INTEGER_EXT, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, data);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

The question is: in my Intel HD (graphics 5500), there will have problem in "glTexImage2D" when I want to deal with the depth camera (in unsigned short), but that is okey for NV (GeForce 940M). (The GL error is 0x0502)
Is the internal format "GL_LUMINANCE16UI_EXT" not suitable for Intel HD? or do I miss something or there have better format can used?

BTW, I had tried the internal format "GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16" with "GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT" to make the error not happened, but some other problem will happen in the following code after the code above:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
frameBuffer.Bind();
glPushAttrib(GL_VIEWPORT_BIT);
glViewport(0, 0, renderBuffer.width, renderBuffer.height);
glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
GlSlProgram Bind;
.
glGetUniformLocation(...);
glUniform3f(...);
.
glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 1);
frameBuffer.Unbind();
GlSlProgram Unbind;
glPopAttrib();
glFinish();
```

The gl error will happen in "glClear" and "glDrawArrays" with 0x0506, when this kind of format is used. I don't know how to fix that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GL_LUMINANCE16UI is no depth buffer format and will most likely not work. A list of available depth buffer formats is [here](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Format#Depth_formats).

also, you probably shouldn't bind the texture itself but instead attach it to the framebuffer with glFrameBufferTexture2D and GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT.

Comment: Thank you very much! actually I am not used to the operation of OpenGL, I will try what you say, thanks again!

Comment: hello karyon, I already use the glFrameBufferTexture2D and GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, and find out that there have no error happened before the "glClear" and "glDrawArrays". Is that any other issue probable?

Comment: apart from making sure you use a proper depth format instead of the luminance thing, i don't know. you can use glCheckFramebufferStatus on your framebuffer, it might give you more detailed info what's going wrong.

Comment: Thanks again Karyon, I find out I get GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT from glCheckFramebufferStatus. And I have tried several methods on web but still can not fix that... maybe I need more try... BTW, is that any possible I  Intel HD (graphics 5500) can not support it?